# how i can Find the files inside the folder and save the file names in variables?

Tags: unix, bash, command-line-interface, search, directory

how i can write bash file to Find files (number and name of files are variable) inside the folder and save the file names in variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in an array.

```
files=(*)
```

Comment: but how i can find it (search about it) inside the folder then i will save it

Comment: ... What does that even mean?

Comment: bash to proccess all files example for what bash do ? folder x contain 5 files bash search fild file no.1 and save name of it in variable y=no.1 ... this bash finshed its work when visit all files

Comment: ... That didn't help. Just use the array.